# I would like to amend my jquery script to add a different #id

Tags: jquery

I have this jquery code which pushes the content down on click:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#showhide').click(function() {
    if($('#author-dropdown').css('display') == 'none') {
      $('#author-dropdown').slideDown();
    } else {
      $('#author-dropdown').slideUp();
    }
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

I would like to add up a different id. So, lets say when the script is to display==none, user should see #author-dropdown and when display==block, the id should be #author-dropdown-extended. How should I amend this script to make it happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#author-dropdown').attr("id","author-dropdown-extended").slideDown();
```

and also change the following to set it back to original state

```
$('#author-dropdown-extended').attr("id","author-dropdown").slideUp();
```

I would personally try something like this though...

```
$('#showhide').click(function() {
    if($('.author-dropdown').is(':hidden')) {
      $('.author-dropdown').slideDown().removeClass('author-dropdown').addClass('author-dropdown-extended');
    } else {
      $('.author-dropdown').slideUp().removeClass('author-dropdown-extended').addClass('author-dropdown');
    }
    return false;
  });
```

Comment: this changes, but it doesnt come up back with #author-dropdown

Comment: Good good... remember to accept the correct answer... it only takes a click!

Comment: Ok, I will do this from now! Also, maybe you will know - lets say that I want to change a class, lets say my author-dropdown is a class, what should I add instead of "id"?

Comment: See edits above... I've used removeClass and addClass so you can add further classes which will not be altered.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you probably shouldn’t dynamically change IDs in documents — use the `class` attribute for that. But you can if you really want to — using jQuery 1.6+:

```
var $elem = $('#author-dropdown');
$elem.prop('id', 'new-id');
```

In older jQuery versions, just use `.attr()` instead of `.prop()`.

Comment: It's not bad to use IDs. It is however bad to use IDs in the way that you are trying to use them... For what you are trying to achieve you would be better assigning a class as well as an ID, then adding/removing the class to alter the appearance of the element

Comment: @Mathias isn't `id` an attribute, rather than a property? So should `attr()` be used rather than `prop()`?

Comment: @StuperUser: It’s an attribute in HTML, of course, but it’s available as a property in DOM0. So you could either use `el.setAttribute('id', 'foo')` (with jQuery: `$el.attr('id', 'foo)`) or `el.id = 'foo'` (with jQuery: `$el.prop('id', 'foo')`). I prefer the latter (a function call is generally much slower than setting a property), but both solutions would have the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Amend this script? Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showhide').click(function() {
        if ($('#author-dropdown').css('display') == 'none') {
            $('#author-dropdown-extended').slideUp('fast', function() {
                $('#author-dropdown').slideDown('slow');
            });
        } else {
            $('#author-dropdown').slideUp('fast', function() {
                $('#author-dropdown-extended').slideDown('slow');
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```