# Javascript or Jquery to change class onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I need to change a class `.author` to `.authornew` when I click.

my html:

```
<div class="meta-info" id="showhide">
    <div class="author"></div>
 <div id="author-dropdown" style="display: none;"></div>
```

My script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#showhide').click(function() {
    if($('#author-dropdown').css('display') == 'none') {
      $('#author-dropdown').attr("id","author-dropdown-extended").slideDown();
    } else {
      $('#author-dropdown-extended').attr("id","author-dropdown").slideUp();
    }
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

`#showhide` is the `id` to press on. `#author-dropdown` is the drop down content. Now, the script changes `id` of drop down content, but I actually need to change class `.author` to `.authornew`. How should I amend my script to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $('div#showhide').click(function() {

           //Check if element with class 'author' exists, if so change it to 'authornew'
           if ($('div.author').length != 0)
                $('div.author').removeClass('author').addClass('authornew');
           //Check if element with class 'authornew' exists, if so change it to 'author'
           else if ($('div.authornew').length != 0)
                $('div.authornew').removeClass('authornew').addClass('author');

       });
   });
</script>
```

This should do the trick!

First it removes the **author** class of your div with class **author**, and it then adds the class **authornew** to the object.

Comment: It changes the class, but it doesnt go back to the previous class, on second click.

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't know you wanted that. Editing my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Updated solution:

If you are just wanting to toggle the `.author` class from `.author` to `.authornew` and back to `.author` on the `click()` event, then you should be able to utilize the `toggle()` function:

HTML:

```
<div class="meta-info" id="showhide">     
    <div class="author">1</div>  
    <div id="author-dropdown" style="display: none;">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.author { background: #000; }
.authornew { background: #ccc; }
```

jQuery:

```
$('#showhide').click(function() { 
    $('div.author').toggleClass('authornew');
});
```

Working example with `toggle()`: http://jsfiddle.net/zydJd/

A simple conditional example would be:

```
var obj = $(this);
if(obj.hasClass('author')){
    obj.removeClass('author').addClass('authornew');
}else{
    obj.removeClass('authornew').addClass('author');
}
```

Where $(this) would reference the object in question, i.e. `$('.author')`.

Or to just make the change then:

```
$('.author').removeClass('author').addClass('authornew');
```

Comment: It changes the class, but it doesnt go back to the previous class, on second click.

Comment: Was not aware you were needing to toggle the classes. Updated solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `addClass` and `removeClass` jQuery methods:

```
$('.author').removeClass('author').addClass('authornew');
```

Comment: Also, it changes the class, but it doesnt go back to the previous class, on second click.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery toggleClass can be useful too.

```
$('#author-dropdown').toggleClass("author authornew");
```

This will toggle the class between author and authornew each time you call it.  It works by removing either that are present and adding either that are not present.  If one is initially present, then it will toggle between the two each time you call it.

Internally, jQuery does a string split on the passed in classnames to isolate each name and then for each className you pass, it does a hasClass on it and if true, it does removeClass, if not true, it does addClass.

Answer (score 0):

This is linked to your previous question. I have added to the answer to your previous question to cover this...

[I would like to amend my jquery script to add a different #id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008289/i-would-like-to-amend-my-jquery-script-to-add-a-different-id/7008401#7008401)